# Calculate total after retriveing tax rate from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 select, 2 text inputs & some JSON data in a form:

- **select input**: List of Suppliers
- **text input 1**: Net Amount
- **text input 2**: Gross Amount
- **JSON Data**:contains the rates of various suppliers as `JSON` in `supplier_tax_rates`

I am calculating Gross Amount something like this(pseudo code):

```
grossAmount = NetAmount + ((currently_selected_supplier.tax_percentage_charged / 100) * netAmount)
```

Here is the complete code:
[Calculate total after retriveing tax rate from JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/A9vmg/17/)

Now, this should work but it doesn't. I get NaN(not a number), means something is wrong. But I have trouble find where.

- [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A9vmg/17/)

Comment: Why Downvote? I am asking a valid question here.  If there something not right about the question, Please comment. I will fix the issue by updating the question.

Comment: How does the demo work? What do I have to enter?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Seems you need to change the Net Amount to get it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code. Here is the correct version:

```
var taxRates = $.parseJSON(supplier_tax_rates);

var getTaxRate = function(id) {
    for (var i in taxRates) {            // correct loop definition
        if (taxRates[i].id == id) {      // check you get id correctly
            return taxRates[i].tax_percentage_charged;   // instead of 'rate'
        }
    }
};

$('#PurchaseNetAmount').on('change', function(event) {
    var taxRatesId = $('#PurchaseSupplierId').val();
    var netAmount = parseFloat(this.value);
    var grossAmount = netAmount + ((getTaxRate(taxRatesId) / 100) * netAmount);
    $('#PurchaseGrossAmount').val(grossAmount);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/A9vmg/18/

Comment: So It seems I was not retrieving/matching value from JSON correctly. Your solution works wonderfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the look up function.

```
 for(TaxRate in supplier_tax_rates ){
```

`supplier_tax_rates` is a string, not a JSON object

Than after you fix that you will have another error

```
 return rate;
```

What is rate?

Learn to use console.log() or breakpoints so you can step throught your code and debug it.

Answer (score -2):

getTaxRate(taxRatesId) return undefined